# WooCommerce Add to cart is not working without login

Tags: nginx, woocommerce

In one of my site, WooCommerce Add to cart is not working without login. My site is hosted in Nginx environment.

Below are the steps I have taken:

1. I exclude full directory from varnish cache but no luck.
2. Same site is working fine in demo server which is Apache server. It is proving that no plugin or theme issue. I have tried default theme and disabled all plugin in live server, but issue persist.
3. Both demo and live server is running 7.0 PHP version.

```
Serverinformation: nginx/1.4.6
PHP-version:7.0.32-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org
WordPress version: 4.9.8
WooCommerce:3.4.7
```

I am seeing my demo server is adding these cookies after click on add to cart but my live server can not adding this types of cookies after click on "add-to_cart" button.

```
    Set-Cookie: woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; path=/
    Set-Cookie: woocommerce_cart_hash=3f15b656…5b85aacf0b278d67f3028; path=/
    Set-Cookie:wp_woocommerce_session_7122db9…9 GMT; Max-Age=172800; path=/
    Set-Cookie:woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; path=/
    Set-Cookie:woocommerce_cart_hash=4dd482cd…2898ff2b261e5751ef008; path=/
    Set-Cookie:wp_woocommerce_session_7122db9…9 GMT; Max-Age=172800; path=/
```

I am not seeing any error in the console also.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: we need more info on that: Do you have access to php/nginx logs. what outputs do you get in devtools under the network-tab, when you click the add-to-cart-button?

Comment: @ad_on_is added the difference between the demo and live server which I am getting in network tab.